# To call login function Only once after pressing 'enter' key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keypress, onkeypress

I'm working on a login function right now. I put my enterKey function in the input, and my aim is to call the login function when the user press the enter key. It works fine if there's nothing in the input area, however, I find that if I have some characters in the input text area, the function will be called multiple times and give multiple error messages.
For example, if I have N characters in the input, I will receive (N+1) error messages after press the enter key.
Here is my code:

```
 enterKeyPress() {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
      if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log('enter key pressed!'); // I will receive this msg (N+1) times when there're N characters in the input text area 
        e.preventDefault();
        this.loginUser(); // this is the login function I want to call after press enter key, but just once per press
      }
    });
  }
 render() {
    return(
      <Input
         type="password"
         placeholder="Password"
         onChange={e =>
            this.setState({ password: e.target.value })
         }
         onKeyPress={this.enterKeyPress()}
      />
    );
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: you're adding an event listener every time a key is pressed

Comment: ^ Thanks for your replies, I really appreciate. I'm thinking of removing event listener once the function is called. Is there a better and simpler solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event listeners aren't necessary in this case.

First thing, adjust `enterKeyPress` to not create an event listener.  If you haven't bound the function in your constructor, then you can convert enterKeyPress to an arrow function:

```
enterKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log('enter key pressed!');
        e.preventDefault();
        this.loginUser();
    });
}
```

Converting `enterKeyPress` to an arrow function is one way to scope the function to the component.  Another option is binding the function in your constructor or in your `render` function, which is well documented elsewhere.  If you've already bound the function in your constructor (you haven't included it here), then you can ignore that part.

Second, adjust your onKeyPress prop to pass the function rather than calling it:

```
<Input
    type="password"
    placeholder="Password"
    onChange={e =>
        this.setState({ password: e.target.value })
    }
    onKeyPress={this.enterKeyPress}
/>
```

It's also worth noting that there's another general JavaScript mistake here: using an anonymous callback function in your event listener.  By using an anonymous function, you're enabling the same function to be added multiple times, since a different function reference is generated each time.  This also means that you won't be able to remove it later, since you'll require the function reference to do so.

Again, you don't need an event listener here, *but if you did*, you should probably define the callback in the component scope, so that you can remove it at some later point.  A common pattern for using event listeners is as follows:

```
handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      console.log('enter key pressed!'); 
      e.preventDefault();
      this.loginUser();
    });
} 

componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("keypress", this.handleKeyPress);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("keypress", this.handleKeyPress);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From some quick Googling, I think this might do what you need:

```
enterKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      console.log('enter key pressed!'); // I will receive this msg (N+1) times when there're N characters in the input text area 
      e.preventDefault();
      this.loginUser(); // this is the login function I want to call after press enter key, but just once per press
    });
}
render() {
    return(
      <Input
         type="password"
         placeholder="Password"
         onChange={e =>
            this.setState({ password: e.target.value })
         }
         onKeyPress={this.enterKeyPress}
      />
    );
}
```

`onKeyPress` already does what the event listener you're trying to add does, so just pass it the keypress event directly instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I already tested this solution and it gave me an error msg like "keyCode is undefined". So I guess I still need the event listener.

Comment: @hikerE Did you remove the parentheses at the end of the function? The way it's written in your question, you aren't allowing the event parameter to be passed through.

Comment: I'm kinda confused, do you mean the parentheses before the semicolon? But that's part of the addeventlistener.

Comment: @hikerE No, in `onKeyPress={this.enterKeyPress}`. That's how all the examples I found used it.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I remove the parentheses it won't call the enterKeyPress function.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ronnie has pointed out in the comments, you are adding a new event listener every time the `onKeyPress` function is triggered on the component, which causes the problems. Since `onKeyPress` event already passes the `event` as an argument (similar to `onClick` event), you can access the `keyCode` from there.

You can change your `enterKeyPress` function to the following:

```
enterKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      console.log('enter key pressed!'); 
      e.preventDefault();
      this.loginUser();
    }
  }
```